# Java references ArrayList

Tags: java, reference, new-operator

I have an ArrayList that I am adding objects to.  Objects are added by using a textbox.

The problem I have is when user enters a value into the textbox, all the entries in my ArrayList take on the new value.

```
if(e.getSource() == textbox){
        String name = textbox.getText();            
        NameSurferEntry entry = new NameSurferEntry();
        entry = db.findEntry(name);
        graph.addEntry(entry);
        graph.update();
        textbox.setText("");

    }
```

Code to add entry:

```
public void addEntry(NameSurferEntry entry) {       
    entryArray.add(entry);          
    }
```

Comment: From the posted code it'll be difficult to help, although I'd be suspicious of the `db.findEntry()` method. The fact that you create a new `NameSurferEntry` then immediately overwrite it is also unusual.

Comment: You're discarding your `new NameSurferEntry` as soon as you create it, which is very suspicious. How does `findEntry` work? What does it return?

Comment: Based on the code that you've posted - you shouldn't be seeing this problem.  Assuming `entryArray` is an `ArrayList<NameSurferEntry>`, then calling the `add` method is the correct way to create a new element at the end of the list, without modifying existing elements.  Are you sure you're describing the problem accurately - if so, then somewhere you must be looping over the ArrayList and updating each value to the same one, which should be quite noticeable.  In any case, your problem lies outside the code you've posted; take a careful look at what you're calling on the list.

Comment: I added the new NameSurferEntry to hopefully create a new object that would go in the arraylist.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new `NameSurferEntry` which you on the next line overwrite with a value from your database. If the returned entry is always the same your arraylist will only contain references to the ***same*** object.

```
NameSurferEntry entry = new NameSurferEntry();
entry = db.findEntry(name);
```

What you should consider is trying to achieve [**immutability**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) in your objects and/or perform **defensive copying**. For simple properties it's enough to declare them `final`, but for complex elements you would typically need to copy the object by creating it anew.

The following sample should work for you, given that you implement the [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12)

```
NameSurferEntry copy = new NameSurferEntry(db.findEntry(name));
```

Comment: I tried adding that before before but db.findEntry() returns a NameSurferEntry object not a string which is required for the constructor.

Comment: @megisto, you have to **implement** such a constructor, or implement some other way to copy the properties from one object to another.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `db.findEntry` always returns the same `NameSurferEntry` instance, and just replaces the name inside it with the name it receives as argument.

Adding an object to an list only adds a reference to the object in the list. It doesn't clone the object to store a copy of it in the list.

BTW, why are you creating a `new NameSurferEntry` and assign it to the entry variable if it's just to overwrite it with the result of `db.findEntry` afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever this is:

```
entry = db.findEntry(name);
```

contains and returns one object, and you're changing whatever it contains.

To be more clear: You're adding the same reference to your list over and over, and changing the contents of the single object that reference points at.

Comment: That's what I thought so I was trying to add a "new" NameSurferEntry.  I don't know how to add a new object to the ArrayList.